# How to get the value of a range slider?

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me how to get values of a range slider in javascript?

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('.slider').on('input change', function(){
            $(this).next($('.slider_label')).html(this.value);
        });
        $('.slider_label').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
            $(this).html(value);
        });


    })
</script>

 <p><label for="range_size">Size: </label> <input type="range" name="size"  class="slider" min="1" max="75" value="45">
                    <span  class="slider_label"></span></p>

                <p><label for="range_width">Width: </label> <input type="range" name="width" class="slider" min="1" max="6" value="1">
                    <span  class="slider_label"></span></p>
```

I am trying to get like this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function calculate () {
                        var size = document.getElementById ("size").value;

alert(size);


</script>
```

But it doesn't show any alert. Can you please help me?

Comment: You are missing the id-tag on your input `<input type="range" id="size"...`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) does work :

```js
let p = document.getElementById("val")
let range = document.getElementById("slide")
let changeVal = () => {
  p.textContent = range.value
}
changeVal()

range.onchange = changeVal
```

```html
<input id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="100"/><p id="val"></p>
```

as [B001ᛦ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4429015/b001%E1%9B%A6) said in comment the problem is you forgot to add an `id` on your `<input>`

---

If you prefer you can also use `name`s but you need to take care as name can be reused while Ids are unique

```js
let p = document.getElementsByName("val")[0]
let range = document.getElementsByName("slide")[0]
let changeVal = () => {
  p.textContent = range.value
}
changeVal()

range.onchange = changeVal
```

```html
<input name="slide" type="range" min="0" max="100"/><p name="val"></p>
```

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/NodeList) so you'll need to get the node you need from this list (the first one if you have only one)

---

as a side note `value` does exists on every input type